# Upgrading to the Google Play version of the Mobile Ads SDK is it mandatory?

Tags: admob, google-play-services

Is upgrading to the Google Play Version of the mobile ads sdk is mandatory for my exist apps and which not need any new updates for meanwhile, and if I didn't upgrade to new SDK does my app's revenues will affect or will be same in serving ads with same bids and revenue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to upgrade if you are planning on deploying a new version of your app.

Your apps with the old version will continue to serve ads. You just won't be able to deploy them to Google Play until you upgrade to the Google Play Services version of Admob after 1st Aug.

Comment: So apps with admob already on the market are fine with no updates after Aug 31st still getting ads and revenue?